# Docker container link not in env or /etc/hosts

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a (global) container running mariadb and an php-fpm container inside a docker-compose.yml. They are linked, but the ip and port of the db container are not in the environment variables of php-fpm.

I started the mariadb container like this:

```
$ docker run --name db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=.... -dP mariadb
```

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: "2"
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80
    links:
      - fpm
    volumes_from:
      - app
  fpm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/fpm/Dockerfile
    external_links:
      - db
    volumes_from:
      - app
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/app/Dockerfile
    volumes:
#      - /app
      - .:/app:ro
```

My fpm Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

Environment variables in phpinfo()

```
PATH    /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME    db14e2928ed6
PHP_INI_DIR /usr/local/etc/php
PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS    --enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data
GPG_KEYS    1A4E8B7277C42E53DBA9C7B9BCAA30EA9C0D5763
PHP_VERSION 7.0.5
PHP_FILENAME    php-7.0.5.tar.xz
PHP_SHA256  c41f1a03c24119c0dd9b741cdb67880486e64349fc33527767f6dc28d3803abb
HOME    /var/www
USER    www-data
```

**Edit:**

I tried linking to an ubuntu container to make sure php-fpm doesn't mess up. It works as a temporary container, but as I put it as external_link in an docker-compose.yaml it disappears from env and /etc/hosts, too.

```
version: "2"
services:
  test:
    image: ubuntu
    external_links:
      - db
```

Comment: The reference says "Note: If you’re using the version 2 file format, the externally-created containers must be connected to at least one of the same networks as the service which is linking to them."

Comment: Version 2 compose files use user defined networking, which does not use `/etc/hosts` anymore. There is an embedded DNS server that handles name resolution.

Comment: How can I access db using the embedded DNS server? I can't resolve `db` (`$ netcat db 3306` `nc: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known`)

Comment: @dnephin It would be great if you could share to answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create a new bridge network, connect the external database container to this network and add the fpm container to the same network.

```
$ docker network create -d bridge dbnetwork
$ docker network connect dbnetwork db
```

And the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80
    links:
      - fpm
    volumes_from:
      - app
  fpm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/fpm/Dockerfile
    external_links:
      - db
    volumes_from:
      - app
    networks:
      - default
      - dbnetwork
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/app/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/app:ro
networks:
  dbnetwork:
    external: true
```

`default` is the default network all other containers inside the docker-compose.yml are connected to. I had to add it, otherwise `fpm` can only talk to the database. The database container can be accessed as `db` or `db.dbnetwork`.